# What is the equivalent of Javascript function closure in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, function, closures

Although Javascript is not like Java, still what is the equivalent of a Javascript function closure in java ? And why do we need closures ?

This is my understanding
1. Private and protected variables in java are accessed by all the methods in that class.
2. Is there a way in which we can increment a private variable giving access to only one method in a class in Java ?
3. If the answer to point 2 is NO, then why is such a requirement satisfied by closures in JavaScript ?
4. Where can we face such a requirement as in point 2 above ?

Comment: Can you give an example of you mean by "js function closure " ?

Comment: Instance variables and methods are basically our alternative to closures. I like them a lot more because you can limit the amount of variables that the method sees.

Comment: I asked why do we need a closure ? And is there any equivalent in java ?

Comment: And that is pretty much too broad.

Comment: In what way, can you kindly explain ?

Comment: Java has lambdas now, and methods defined in anonymous inner classes could always access `final` variables in their enclosing lexical scope, as well as any instance variables of the object they were declared in. (Since what java basically does is that it copies the values of the final local variables, and of the enclosing `this`, into the AIC instance being created.)

Comment: And that is what even I am saying that we cannot restrict this access in java but we can do so in Javascript (I may be completely wrong in saying so) If I am please kindly explain...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish though? The JavaScript pattern of using a function scope to hide some state of an object you're returning to the caller is usually done to replicate `private` and `protected` fields, so just use those.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you dont need "closure". All that you have in a function is only for this function, you should try dont use static for everything.

Java is OO, a variable in a object can be accesed by all methods from this Object. If you dont want other object acces to it, use "private" tag.

```
//Class
public class HelloWorld(){
  private int var1;
  public String var2;

  // Constructor
  public HelloWorld(){
  }

  public void function1(){
    //here you can use var1 and var2.
  }

  private void function2(){
    //here you can use var1 and var2.
  }

  // If you have a parameter with same name, you should use this
  private void  function3(int var1){
    // this.var1 object variable
    // var1 method variable
  }
}

//From another object:
public class ByeWorld(){

  private HelloWorld anInstanceOfHelloWorld;

  public ByeWorld(){
    anInstanceOfHelloWorld = new HelloWorld();

    // var2 is public you can use it (NO RECOMENDABLE) 
    anInstanceOfHelloWorld.var2;
    anInstanceOfHelloWorld.function1();

    // YOU CANT
    // anInstanceOfHelloWorld.var1 // is private
    // anInstanceOfHelloWorld.function2() // is private
    //...
  }
}
```

I hope this help you something.